# React + Express + SQLite Deployment With Heroku Gives 404 on Get="/"

Tags: reactjs, sqlite, express, heroku, react-router

I am attempting to deploy a `create-react-app` on Heroku with an Express server connected to a SQLite database. Everything works fine in development, however, in production  the following log is generated where `method=GET path="/"` returns a `404`.

```
2020-05-30T03:22:53.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-05-30T03:22:54.639920+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command npm start
2020-05-30T03:22:57.641882+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-05-30T03:22:57.641918+00:00 app[web.1]: > heroku-app@0.1.0 start /app
2020-05-30T03:22:57.641919+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server
2020-05-30T03:22:57.641919+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-05-30T03:22:58.146414+00:00 app[web.1]: Node listening on port 15383
2020-05-30T03:22:58.147490+00:00 app[web.1]: Connected to material failures database
2020-05-30T03:22:58.697030+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-05-30T03:23:25.514258+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=frozen-cliffs-13786.herokuapp.com request_id=24311843-65ba-49df-8464-195716354495 fwd="205.206.229.151" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=18ms status=404 bytes=493 protocol=https
```

I call the router in `react-ui/src/index.js`

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie9';
import 'react-app-polyfill/stable';

// CSS
import './css/main.css';

import React    from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Router from './components/router.component.js';

ReactDOM.render( <React.StrictMode> <Router /> </React.StrictMode>, document.getElementById( 'root' ) );
```

My folder structure is as follows:

```
heroku-app
    react-ui
       node_modules
       public
       src
       .gitignore
       package-lock.json
       package.json
    server
    .gitignore
    app.json
    package.json
    package-lock.json
    static.json
```

I have honestly tried everything such as:

1. Adding a `static.json`

```
{
  "root": "react-ui/build/",
  "clean_urls": false,
  "routes": {
    "/**": "index.html"
  }
}
```

2. Adding a 'catch-all' in my `server/index.js` file. I have tried `*`, `/*` and `/`

```
const path        = require( 'path' );
const express     = require( 'express' );
const bodyParser  = require( 'body-parser' );
const compression = require( 'compression' );
const cors        = require( 'cors' );
const helmet      = require( 'helmet' );
const router      = require( './router.js' );

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const app  = express();


app.use( cors() )
app.use( helmet() )
app.use( compression() )
app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded( { extended: false } ) )
app.use( bodyParser.json() )

app.use( '/api', router )

app.use( function ( err, req, res, next ) 
{
    console.error( err.stack )

    res.status( 500 ).send( 'Response 500: Server Error. Very Frustrating!' )
} )

app.use( function ( req, res, next ) 
{
    res.status( 404 ).send( 'Response 400: Page Not Found. Hmmmm...' )
} )

app.use( express.static( path.resolve( __dirname, '../react-ui/build' ) ) );

app.get( '*', function( request, response ) 
{
    response.sendFile( path.resolve( __dirname, '../react-ui/build', 'index.html' ) );
} );

app.listen( PORT, function () 
{
    console.error( `Node listening on port ${ PORT }` );
} );
```

3. Adding `homepage` to the two `package.json` files. I have tried `.` and `https://frozen-cliffs-13786.herokuapp.com/`

**In root...**

```
{
  "name": "heroku-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage":".",
  "description": "materials failure database web application",

  "engines": {
    "node": "10.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server",
    "build": "cd react-ui && npm install && npm run build"
  },
  "cacheDirectories": [
    "node_modules",
    "react-ui/node_modules"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "helmet": "^3.22.0",
    "sqlite3": "^4.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/joleneborrelli-uofa/material-failures-database.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "node",
    "heroku",
    "create-react-app",
    "react"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

**In react-ui...**

```
{
  "name": "react-ui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "homepage":".",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

4. Interchanging between `BrowserRouter` and `HashRouter`, with and without a `basename` property in `react-ui/src/components/router.component.js`

```
import React    from 'react';
import Homepage from './homepage.component.js';
import Page     from './page.component.js';

// React Router
import 
{
  BrowserRouter,
  Switch,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";


export default function Router()
{
    return (
        <BrowserRouter basename={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/`}>
            <div>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={ Homepage } />
                    <Route path="/:page/:id" exact component={ Page } />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
};
```

I may pull my hair out soon.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the problem was that the `react-ui` folder was its own git repository, which is what happens during the `create-react-app` stage.

The answer was found [here](https://dev.to/nburgess/creating-a-react-app-with-react-router-and-an-express-backend-33l3) in the comments...

"Be sure to remove the git folder (generated by Create React App) in the client directory. Doing so will allow Heroku to build your React app and fix the "Not Found" error."